# Drop SQLite tables using list of tables names

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8.1

I am trying to `drop a collection of tables` by using tables names in the list and then get the type of each string and drop it :

```
List<string> models = new List<string> { "WebBrowser", "Notebook", "Members"};

foreach (string mod in models)
{

    Type type = Type.GetType(mod));
    using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(app.DBPath))
    {
        dbConn.RunInTransaction(() =>
        {
            dbConn.DropTable<type>();
            //dbConn.DropTable<WebBrowser>();
            dbConn.Dispose();
            dbConn.Close();
        });
    }
}
```

**Problem** : I can't drop table using this way, **DropTable** need the name of class (e.g **WebBrowser** ) and I don't want to drop each table alone (i.e dbConn.DropTable< WebBrowser >();) since I have more than 50 tables to drop.

**Error** : "The type or namespace name '**type**' could not be found". ( and this error is expected since there is no Class 'type' in my Namespace .

Comment: Please, try to specify better (for me at least) where is the problem: the code does not compile ? or the problem is about retrive all model names ?

Comment: of course, the code will not compile, this code will give you: The type or namespace name 'type' could not be found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drop tables using a SQL command in SQLite. All you need to do is iterate over your collection and build a SQL string each time, and execute it

```
List<string> models = new List<string> { "WebBrowser", "Notebook", "Members"};

foreach (string mod in models)
{
    using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(app.DBPath))
    {
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(dbConn);
        command.CommandText = string.Format("DROP TABLE {0};", mod);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this syntax is exactly correct for your case (I only ever use sqlite-net in Windows 8.1) but the general approach is sound

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own Extensionmethod like this:

```
public static class SQLiteConnectionExtensions
{
    public static int DropTable(this SQLiteConnection conn, string tableName)
    {
        var query = string.Format("drop table if exists \"{0}\"", tableName);
        return conn.Execute(query);
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
var tables = new List<string> { "WebBrowser", "Notebook", "Members" };

using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(app.DBPath))
{
    dbConn.RunInTransaction(() =>
    {
        foreach (string table in tables)
        {
            dbConn.DropTable(table);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Reflections. Here are the two extension methods:

```
public static void DropTable(this SQLiteConnection Connection, Type TableType)
{
    typeof(SQLiteConnection).GetMethod("DropTable", Array.Empty<Type>())?.MakeGenericMethod(TableType).Invoke(Connection, null);
}

public static void DropTable(this SQLiteConnection Connection, Type[] AllTableTypes)
{
    MethodInfo? Method = typeof(SQLiteConnection).GetMethod("DropTable", Array.Empty<Type>());
    if (Method != null)
    {
        foreach (Type? OneTableType in AllTableTypes)
        {
            Method.MakeGenericMethod(OneTableType).Invoke(Connection, null);
        }
    }
}
```

You can call them on a SQLiteConnection object:

```
TheSqlLiteConnection.DropTable(typeof(SomeClass));
TheSqlLiteConnection.DropTable(new Type[] { typeof(SomeClass), typeof(SomeOtherClass) });
```